# mysql count records from two tables in one query?

Tags: mysql, count

I have three MySQL-tables:

```
patient:
    paID, paCode, paAccountID (foreign key)

test
    tsID, tsName, tsPatientID (foreign key), tsAccountID (foreign key)

account
    acID etc.
```

Now I want to count the number of `paID` and the number of `tsID` that are linked to a specific `acID=1`. There are 6 `tsID` and 4 `paID` linked to `acID=1`.

```
SELECT Count(paID) AS paCount FROM patient WHERE paAccountID=1
SELECT Count(tsID) AS tsCount FROM test WHERE tsAccountID=1
```

Tried to get both into one query...

```
SELECT Count(tsID) AS tsCount, Count(paID) AS paCount
FROM test LEFT JOIN patient ON tsPatientID = paID 
WHERE tsAccountID=1
```

Doesn't work that way, both Counts return 6. How to get it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work assuming your tsId and paId are unique keys:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT t.tsID) AS tsCount, 
    Count(DISTINCT p.paID) AS paCount
FROM account a 
    LEFT JOIN test t ON a.acId = t.tsAccountId
    LEFT JOIN patient p ON a.acId = p.paAccountId
WHERE a.acId = 1
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb1bf4/1).

Please note: the problem with not joining on the account table (and using it as the master table) is that if either the test table or the patient table have no data for a specific account id, the query will return 0 results for each -- which could be incorrect.

Comment: @michi -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT tsID) AS tsCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT paID) AS paCount
FROM
    test
    CROSS JOIN patient
WHERE
    tsAccountID = 1
    AND paAccountID = 1
```

Comment: returns 24 for both counts, guess it's the distinct that's missing.

Comment: @ExplosionPills -- I wouldn't join test as your main table -- what if no results exist in test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/417e1/1 -- I used account as my primary table.  Other than that, looks good!

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` is less typing, too ;-)

Comment: @michi note that you don't have to actually type the `CROSS`, it's just to indicate that this is a cross join.  You could just type `JOIN` and it would have the same effect

Comment: @michi -- be careful with CROSS JOINs -- they won't work if either table have no data -- see Fiddle above.  That's where the LEFT JOIN is probably a better approach...  Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

your join method returns all rows that are related, thus your count will always return the number of all the rows returned

in such cases I'd use a (select count(*) from [Table] Where [id=x]) as [tsCount]) inside the main select query as a field .. that