# Count multiple columns from different tables php

Tags: php

I'm trying to count two different tables but it's not working, and I cannot find out where the problem is, and how to implement it with PHP.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(users.user_id) AS totalUsers FROM users, SELECT COUNT(bikes.bike_id) AS totalBikes FROM bikes";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<td><td>" . $row["totalUsers"] . "</td></tr>";
                echo "<td><td>" . $row["totalBikes"] . "</td></tr>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
    
        $conn->close();
```

Comment: You can't have 2 selects in one query like that. You need 2 different queries to coun the rows from 2 different tables.

Comment: @PauloAmaral I think I understand what you're saying, but how would be in code? I'm struggling a bit to imagine the code for what you are describing.

Comment: I wrote the code in the answer below, see if it makes more sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql count records from two tables in one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916658/mysql-count-records-from-two-tables-in-one-query)

Answer (score 0):

Get the amounts from each table separately. Each `SELECT` is a unique resultset from your query, listing them with commas won't retrieve all data as you are expecting.

```php
$result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(users.user_id) AS totalUsers FROM users");
$totalUsers = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $totalUsers = $row["totalUsers"];
}

$result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(bikes.bike_id) AS totalBikes FROM bikes");
$totalBikes = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $totalBikes = $row["totalBikes"];
}

$conn->close();
```

Then you can work with the values stored in `$totalUsers` and `$totalBikes`:

```php
echo "<tr><td>" . $totalUsers . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>" . $totalBikes . "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: But that does not insert count in a table in HTML though?

Comment: This is how you get the data you are looking for. To write HTML you would do something like `echo "<td><td>" . $totalUsers . "</td></tr>";` (without the `while`).

Comment: But the while loop is fetching the results though? So how would that work?

Comment: I just fixed the answer and added a table example. Since the result of each query will have just one value, you don't need a loop, you can call `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` just one time and read the value, for each query.